# Careers PDF export - it lists items in the Apps & Software section in wrong order

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, export

In my Careers 2.0 profile I specified some apps I've written.

Then I changed the order the apps are listed in on my profile. Unfortunately I then noticed the PDF export, it lists my apps in the original order that I entered them.

Is there any chance under the Projects & Interests section to show them in the order I've sorted them in my profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change has been made and will go out with the next push.

Comment: thanks - great to see such a speedy response to tech features.